# How do I run a function on start-up?

Tags: init-file, spacemacs, linum-mode

How do I run an arbitrary function upon starting up Emacs?

My specific problem: in `spacemacs`, I have added the following to the config section of my `.spacemacs` file:

```
(add-hook 'evil-insert-state-exit-hook 'linum-relative-on)
(add-hook 'evil-insert-state-entry-hook 'linum-relative-off)
```

It works well, but I've noticed that this config produces weird behaviour if I don't first execute `linum-relative-toggle` immediately after opening `spacemacs` and before editing a file.

How can I get Emacs to automatically execute `linum-relative-toggle` on start up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two basic options to run a function (in this case, `linum-relative-toggle`) at start-up.

Simple option: add `(linum-relative-toggle)` to your `init` file (probably at the end).

Somewhat more involved option (may be necessary if the simple option doesn't help for some reason): use `(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'linum-relative-toggle)`.

`after-init-hook`'s docstring:

> **Normal hook run after initializing the Emacs session.**
>   It is run after Emacs loads the init file, `default` library, the
>   abbrevs file, and additional Lisp packages (if any), and setting
>   the value of `after-init-time`.